# How to make a function randomly choose a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, random, key

I need to make a function which randomly chooses a key from a dictionary.
I'm not quite sure how to do that!

Help?

Comment: `random.choice(list({'a': 1, 'b': 2}))` → `'b'` @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ your code will work until Python 3.5.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ even though dicts are not ordered in earlier python versions, the order is far from random, so I would not advocate that

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Became little lazy :D

Comment: list_of_keys = list()
for i in atom_dict.keys():
        list_of_keys.append(i)
        print(list_of_keys)

Comment: I wrote it like this but i'm still fairly uncertain on how to make it random! :(